# How to convert Gradle to maven in eclipse

Tags: java, maven, gradle, migration

I want to migrate from gradle to maven I tried and build successfully but I am facing issue while running my application

I took this gradle project https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-kerberos from git, its working fine as gradle project.

But my requirement is maven project please tell me how I can do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and add the [Maven Publishing](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html) plugin and its [maven-publish](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html#sec:the_mavenpublish_plugin) in order to generate a `pom.xml`.

> A `MavenPublication` is the representation/configuration of how Gradle should publish something in Maven format.
>   You directly add a named Maven Publication the project's `publishing.publications` container by providing `MavenPublication` as the type.

```
publishing {
  publications {
    myPublicationName(MavenPublication) {
      // Configure the publication here
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using `archiveTask` you can generate the pom.xml
http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html#sec:maven_pom_generation